# How do I return to the cqlsh prompt if I make a mistake?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Whenever i make a mistake in the query, cassandra cqlsh will show the error below.

```
> use TESTDB 
. 
. 
. 
. 
. 
Statements are terminated with a ';'.  You can press CTRL-C to cancel an incomplete statement.
```

Pressing CTRL-C will bring me back to the Windows shell. I dont want to always exit CQLSH just because of syntax error. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

CQL statements need to be terminated with a semi-colon (`;`).

All you need to do is type in `;` then hit `<Enter>` to get the cqlsh prompt back. Even if your CQL statement is incorrect, cqlsh will just report an error and give you back the prompt. Cheers!